# Showreel feedback 

Tags: showreel

Hello i've just uploaded my first attempt at a sound design showreel and thought it would be a good idea to get some feedback off like-minded people. It can be viewed here

http://vimeo.com/31798677

Thanks
Adam

Comment: page not found :(

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry I updated it here's the link to the new one

http://vimeo.com/37663800

Comment: Hi @Adam can you edit your original question with the correct link please? https://vimeo.com/37663800 also "Sorry, we couldn’t find that page"

Answer (score 1):

In the first clip, what's the deal with the voices? Even if that's not your work it distracts from everything else. Fun job with Wall-E although some objects don't sound like they are in that scenario. Very nice work with the dialogue editing.
And by the way, congrats on the Designing Sound Challenge. Real nice!

Comment: Yeah that doesn't make sense much as I've cut a bit from half way through the film, it's meant to be echoes of things that have been said from earlier in the film. Maybe I need to put them a bit lower in the mix. Thank you for your feedback. 

Comment: @Adam I meant the dialogue. The voice of the guy in the chair is very very low. There are other ways of making it sound far away if that's the purpose. The reel starts ok but as soon as the first clip initiates, anyone listening will probably turn up the volume. The echoes are fine and serve they purpose.